# Calculating length of vertical line bisecting parallel arcs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

I have 2 arcs, offset from one another (never intersecting) and a vertical line through them both (NOT at the center of the arcs). Is there a way to calculate the vertical distance between the 2 arcs? It changes depending on where along the arc the vertical line is.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give the algebraic formula for the curves you're using. Without it, it's impossible to give a precise answer for what you're looking for. In fact, if you write down the equations (I presume for two circles centered around the origin), you might find the solution to actually be very simple.

Comment: I'm given the width of the chord that defines the arc as well as the arc height (from that chord) and from that I can derive the radius and the arc length. So that's the information I have to work with. Is that what you mean?

Comment: $ h \approx  w /\cos \phi $  where w is offset, $\phi$ slope or angle to horizontal, $h$ is vertical line height or length.

Comment: Can you describe a little further what exactly you mean by this: ϕ slope or angle to horizontal ?
I'm sorry but it has been way too long since I've done math like this.

Answer (score 0):

If the two equations are
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$,
the obvious answer is
$g(x)-f(x)$.

If,
as suggested by
 Monstrous Moonshine,
the two curves
are the upper half of circles,
then the curves are
$f(x)
=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}
$
and
$g(x)
=\sqrt{s^2-x^2}
$,
where
$s > r > 0$.

The distance is then,
doing some fiddling with the expression
for the heck of it,

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)-f(x)
&= \sqrt{s^2-x^2}-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\\
&= (\sqrt{s^2-x^2}-\sqrt{r^2-x^2})\dfrac{\sqrt{s^2-x^2}+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{\sqrt{s^2-x^2}+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{(s^2-x^2)-(r^2-x^2)}{\sqrt{s^2-x^2}+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{s^2-r^2}{\sqrt{s^2-x^2}+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\\
\end{array}
$

For other curves,
just put in the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If the rings are circular and concentric

$$h = \sqrt{R^2- x^2}-\sqrt{r^2- x^2} $$

For a narrow ring width:

$$  w = R-r, h \approx  w /\cos \phi $$